# Ubuntu 22.04 - "Connection Failed: Activation of Network Failed" - VMware

Tags: wireless, network-manager, vmware, 22.04, connection

I recently installed an Ubuntu 22.04 distribution on my Virtual Machine (VMware Workstation 16 Player) in order to run Docker. In order to connect the VM to the internet, I'm using an USB WiFi Adapter (TP-Link TL-WN823N V3).

Nearly every time, I try to establish an Internet connection, it doesn't work saying "Activation of network connection failed" from the Network popup window. I managed to establish a stable connection twice, all other attempts failed.

I did several restarts and tried out many other suggestions from the web (e.g. https://appuals.com/activation-of-network-connection-failed-in-linux/) - with no effect.

Output of network hardware devices:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
 *-network
      description: Wireless interface
      physical ID: 6
      bus info: usb@1:1
      logical name: wlx7cc2cc60656cc
      serial: 7c:c2:c6:06:56:cc
      capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=5.15.0-30-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Output of `iwconfig`:

```
$ iwconfig
lo       no wireless extensions

ens33    no wireless extensions

wlx7cc2c60656cc  IEEE- 802.11  ESSID:off/any
         Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
         Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
         Power Management:off
```

Status of `NetworkManager`:

```
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since ...
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 2718 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4588)
   Memory: 3.5M
      CPU: 223ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           '-2718 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Mai 24 12:18:00 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <info> [1653387480.6275] device (wlx7cc2c60656cc): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mai 24 12:18:01 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <info> [1653387481.3939] device (wlx7cc2c60656cc): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mai 24 12:18:11 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <info> [1653387491.4318] device (wlx7cc2c60656cc): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mai 24 12:18:15 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <info> [1653387495.0670] device (wlx7cc2c60656cc): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mai 24 12:18:15 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <info> [1653387495.8433] device (wlx7cc2c60656cc): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mai 24 12:18:19 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <warn> [1653387499.7984] device (wlx7cc2c60656cc): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Mai 24 12:18:19 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <info> [1653387499.7985] device (wlx7cc2c60656cc): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mai 24 12:18:19 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <info> [1653387499.7989] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mai 24 12:18:19 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <warn> [1653387499.7990] device (wlx7cc2c60656cc): Activation: failed for connection '<wifi-name>'
Mai 24 12:18:19 virtual-machine NetworkManager1[2718]: <info> [1653387499.7991] device (wlx7cc2c60656cc): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Any help on how to fix this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this after trying everything and it worked reference: https://tutorialforlinux.com/2022/10/06/troubleshooting-ubuntu-22-04-vmware-virtual-machine-no-internet-connection/

**this** part seems to fix it, run in terminal:

```
sudo dhclient -v
```

I set my network to bridged from the VMware network settings page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).